# Need to figure out how to scan trough combinations

Tags: c, loops, game-theory

I have been working on a slot machine code and I have the reels input and I coded all the different combinations that can occur. I output it to a file and sure enough everything is there. Now I need to somehow scan all the combinations and based on rules for payments (2x, 3x and 5x the same symbol) and rules that if 2 wins are there ex. `aabbb` that only the higher paying one will be paid out, make counters for all the payout conditions.

Here is what I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    freopen("C:\\tmp\\output.txt", "w", stdout);
    char reel1[37] = { 'A', '1', 'W', 'Q', '9', 'L', '1', 'J', 'H', 'Q', '9', 'W', '1', 'A', 'M', 'K', 'Q', 'L', 'A', '9', '1', 'M', 'K', 'Q', 'H', '9', 'A', 'Q', 'K', 'T', '9', 'J', 'W', '9', '1', 'L', '9' };
    char reel2[36] = { 'A', 'K', 'L', '1', '9', 'M', 'J', '1', 'K', 'M', 'Q', '9', 'T', 'A', '1', 'Q', 'W', 'K', '9', 'L', 'J', '1', 'Q', 'L', 'K', 'J', 'W', 'A', '9', 'K', 'H', 'Q', '1', 'K', 'Q', '1' };
    char reel3[35] = { 'J', 'K', '9', 'A', '1', 'Q', 'L', '9', 'A', '1', 'T', 'J', '9', 'A', 'H', '1', 'J', '9', 'L', 'Q', '1', 'J', 'H', '9', 'K', '1', 'M', 'A', 'J', 'K', 'W', '9', '1', 'J', '1' };
    char reel4[32] = { 'K', 'A', 'L', 'Q', '1', 'M', 'A', 'K', 'J', 'M', 'Q', '1', 'H', 'J', 'A', 'K', 'M', '9', 'J', 'H', '1', 'Q', '9', 'J', '1', 'W', 'K', '9', 'J', 'T', '1', 'J' };
    char reel5[32] = { 'J', '1', 'Q', 'W', 'K', '9', 'Q', 'J', 'K', '9', '1', 'H', 'J', '9', 'A', 'M', '9', 'J', '1', '9', 'L', 'A', '9', 'J', 'L', '9', 'K', 'Q', '9', 'T', 'K', 'Q' };
    int a, b, c, d, e;
    for (a = 0; a <= 36; a++) {
        for (b = 0; b <= 35; b++) {
            for (c = 0; c <= 34; c++) {
                for (d = 0; d <= 31; d++) {
                    for (e = 0; e <= 31; e++) {
                        printf("%c%c%c%c%c\n", reel1[a], reel2[b], reel3[c], reel4[d], reel5[e]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

How do I tackle this now? I know that I have to put up counters for all the payout combinations and once it shows up and is the highest paying one on the reel, to iterate it by one until I have gone trough the whole list. But how to get there beats me. How to scan all the combinations? Anyone have suggestions?

Comment: Too much nesting!

Comment: Suggestion: it is more consistent to write `for (a = 0; a < 37; a++)` instead of `for (a = 0; a <= 36; a++)` as the array has `37` values.  You could even write `for (a = 0; a < (int)(sizeof(reel1) / sizeof(*reel1)); a++)` to avoid relying on hard coded values.

Comment: @chqrlie Thanks, I changed it to that. About the hardcoded values, well right now it doesn't matter much to me, since all I need for this to do is to run trough all this once and give me what I need.

Comment: I have done something similar: [Brute Force](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TodorBalabanov/booming-games-simple-task/master/src/Main.java)

Answer (score 0):

Your code does print all 47,738,880 possible combinations of slot values.  There will be many duplicates as the wheels have duplicate items and the order probably does not matter.

Here is how you could proceed: instead of printing the combinations, call a function with the 5 slot values that will:

- check the various winning combinations and keep the best one
- output the combination along with the corresponding best win.

Then you can run the program and pipe its output to `sort | uniq -c` to get a listing with duplicates removed (and counted).

You might want to omit the losing combinations in the listing.

In addition to printing the winning combinations, you could compute the total possible wins (the sum of all wins as computed above) and divide that by the total number of outputs (37*36*35*32*32) to verify what the odds are for the player and the casino.

Comment: Well I forgot to mention that "All symbols pay from left to right". Does that impact what you stated above? About the duplicates and such? Because even if, let's say reel 1 has 2 A symbols, and the other 4 have one A symbol, that is still 2 different ways that 5xA can come up on the screen. I hope you get what I'm saying.

Comment: @SanJasko: if the combinations pay based on the order of values, do not sort the values. This will just produce more total combinations, but there will still be many duplicates in the listing.

Comment: How am I going to have duplicates? and even if I have them, they would still count as winning combinations. Because let's say I have AAA99 and AAA90 and AAAKJ, those three are still winning combinations. And even if AAA99 shows up again and it's different than the first one since there are two 9 on the 4th and 5th reel, it's still a winning combination. That's how I am seeing it.

Comment: @SanJasko: you are going to have millions of duplicates because the reels have duplicate values. You should still count them as winning combinations to get the stats right, but you could combine them in the final listing.

Comment: Oh, yeah, well I need all of them, considering that there are 47,738,880 combinations all together. By the way, how do I tackle the fact that W can change into any other character. Sorry, I forgot to mention that. Do I just count the winning combinations for it like normal, or should I make a new loop to check all of that. And if yes, any suggestions on how to start on it?

Comment: @SanJasko: I would handle the wildcard in the combination assessment function.

Comment: So I would have to make another counter to compare all payout values and then use the ones with the wildcard or the normal ones based on the amount it pays?

Comment: if let's say I have WTTAT would that be considered a winning combination? Sure, W can turn into any other symbol, but reading from left to right the second isn't a match. But then again, since it can change into any other, it could become TTTAT which is a winning one. Damn it.

Comment: @SanJasko: it is also my understanding that WTTAT is a winning combination with the value of `TTTAT`. The code to compute the value of a combination might be somewhat tedious depending on what the winning combinations are, but you did not post any details.